# How to add shared Printer on Redhat

Tags: rhel, printer

One of the customer requested to enabled Printer Sharing between Redhat Linux Server and the Printer which is shared on one the Windwos 7 Machine.

The path they provided is \192.168.16.105\SharedPrinter

I tried to access the printer using system-config-printer but this Sharedname didnt show up.

Now how can i enable this SharedPrinter on Redhat server ???

Comment: Have you sorted the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the main I have used the SAMBA package on a Windows server for printing from RedHat, SuSe and Mint. I have also used GhostScript to utilise a printer connected to a Windows XP PC. This requires the SAMBA client and CUPS to be installed and running on your RedHat system. I cannot remember the details but if you Google these terms I am sure you will find them.